# how to display db result in form_dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter

**I wanna display this query result as form_dropdown**

**Model**

```
public function deptlist_view() {
    $this -> load -> database();
    $query = $this -> db -> query('select var_staffdepartment from tbl_admin');
    return $query -> result();

}
```

**Controller**

```
public function view_dept() {
    $this -> load -> model('model_database');
    $deptdata['query'] = $this -> model_users -> deptlist_view();

    $this -> load -> view('signup', $deptdata);

}
```

**View**

```
     <?php $dept= ????  ?>



        <?php echo form_open('welcome/signup_validation'); ?>

         <table align="center">


    <tr>
   <td>
    <p> Departments :</p>
    </td>
            <td><?php  echo form_dropdown('staffdept', $dept); ?></td>


                        </table>

                    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Could you please show how to fix this Problem? It would be very helpfull. thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the dropdown options in an array like..

```
 $options = array(
               'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
              'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
              'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
              'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
            );
```

so i created a new array .. added options in correct array format and displayed in the view

try this

**Controller**

```
public function view_dept() {
  $this -> load -> model('model_database');
  $query = $this -> model_users -> deptlist_view();
  $tempArray=array();
  foreach($query as $row){
     $tempArray[$row->var_staffdepartment]=$row->var_staffdepartment;
  }
  $data['department']=$tempArray;
   $this -> load -> view('signup', $data);

}
```

**view**

```
 <?php echo form_open('welcome/signup_validation'); ?>

  <table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p> Departments :</p>
    </td>
    <td><?php  echo form_dropdown('staffdept', $department); ?></td>
   </table>

    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
public function view_dept() 
{
  $this->load->model('model_database');
  $query = $this->model_users->deptlist_view();
  $data['staffdept'] = $query->result(); //
  $this->load->view('signup', $data);
}
```

View:

```
<?php
    $options = array('Select a department'); 
    foreach ($staffdept as $staff):
        $options[$staff->ID] = $staff->name; //insert the sql query results here
    endforeach;
    echo form_dropdown('staffdept', $options, $staff->ID);
?>
```

To add a class or ID to the dropdown, edit the last 'echo form_dropdown' line in your code

```
$other = "id='staffdept', class='staffdept'";
echo form_dropdown('staffdept', $options, $staff->ID, $other);
```